# Create json with a string variable as argument using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to create a json file using a variable somewhat like this:

input:

```
ss="mango"
jq -n '{"name": {"S": $ID}}' --arg ID 'partridge in a $ss tree'
```

actual output:

```
{
  "name": {
    "S": "partridge in a $ss tree"
  }
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  "name": {
    "S": "partridge in a mango tree"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `jq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `--arg ID "value"` in double quote like following:

```sh
ss="mango"
jq -n '{"name": {"S": $ID}}' --arg ID "partridge in a $ss tree"
```

---

output:

```json
{
  "name": {
    "S": "partridge in a mango tree"
  }
}
```